# Remove erroneous timeout that is set to zero

Tags: javascript, timeout

The timeout of 0 is used here so that the keypress has time to end before blurring the control. This strikes me as the wring way to achieve this...

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if( e.keyCode === 13){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('input').blur();
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

What is a better way to blur controls when the enter key is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `setTimeout` here:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if( e.keyCode === 13){
      $('input').blur();
  }
});
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7wWke/)***

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using `keyup` event, so that you have a small amount of time before the user releases the key.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if( e.keyCode === 13){
      $('input').blur();
  }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/esWaf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You might be surprised to learn that there is no such thing as a timeout of zero. The minimum timeout value of Chrome is 8ms and the minimum of Firefox is 15ms.

Comment: Although rare, there may be some cases where timeout of 0 does indeed exist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7221609/665261